# »Anfangs« oder »Zuerst«?

Tags: word-choice, difference

Laut Duden sind *anfangs* und *zuerst* Synonyme. Diese beiden Sätze sagen also dasselbe:

> Zuerst empfand ich noch wenig Sympathie für meinen Kollegen Klaus.
>   Anfangs empfand ich noch wenig Sympathie für meinen Kollegen Klaus.

Mir scheinen die Wörter aber doch einen vagen Bedeutungsunterschied zu haben:

Beim Beispiel mit *zuerst* erwarte ich eher eine Aufzählung, eine Reihe von darauffolgenden Entwicklungsschritten der Gefühle:

> Zuerst wenig Sympathie, dann mehr, und zuletzt verliebte ich mich sogar in ihn.

Beim Beispiel mit *anfangs* erwarte ich dagegen eher eine Wendung:

> Anfangs wenig Sympathie, dann jedoch lernte ich die Gründe für sein Verhalten kennen.

Daneben wirkt *anfangs* etwas schriftsprachlicher, formeller, gehobener auf mich, jedenfalls kommt es mir unvertrauter vor, aber die Häufigkeitsangabe im Duden ist bei beiden Wörtern gleich.

**Was sind die Unterschiede in der Bedeutung und Verwendung?**

Comment: Man kann viel hineininterpretieren, aber in der Praxis sehe ich da keinen Unterschied. Beim Hineininterpretieren besteht immer die Gefahr, dass anderen solche Finessen der Unterscheidung nicht geläufig sind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Zuerst* hat zwei Anwendungsgebiete. Das eine ist synonym zu *anfangs*. Weitere Synonyme in dem Kontext:

- *am Anfang*, *zu Beginn*, *anfänglich*, *zunächst*

Es kann jedoch auch in einer Aufzählung verwendet werden.

- *als Erstes*, *zuallererst*

Hier steht es dann in Kontrast zu *zuletzt*, *als Letztes*. Alles, was dazwischen liegt, kann mit *danach*, *als Nächstes*, *anschließend* eingeleitet werden.
Dies alles kann *anfangs* nicht ausdrücken und kann daher nicht in einer Aufzählung verwendet werden. Der folgende Satz ist demnach 'falsch':

> *Anfangs empfand ich nur Sympathie, als Nächstes/anschließend/hernach/danach verliebte ich mich aber sogar.

Korrekt eingeleitet wäre der zweite Teil mit *später*, *zu einem späteren Zeitpunkt*.

Referenzierst du also auf den Anfangszeitpunkt, so kannst du *anfangs* und *zuerst* gleichermaßen verwenden. Ich sehe hier keinen Unterschied in Konnotation oder Sprachregister oder sonst was.

Answer (score 0):

Mir scheint, dass *anfangs* die Kenntnis des weiteren Verlaufs voraussetzt und deshalb nur im Rückblick möglich ist oder in der Verallgemeinerung ("immer"):

> Anfangs **war** er noch sehr schüchtern, später öffnete er sich uns dann.
>
> Anfangs gehe ich **immer** langsam, später dann gehe ich schnell.
>
> Anfangs ist er **immer** schüchtern, später öffnet er sich dann immer.

Nur mit *zuerst* kann man auch über die Gegenwart schreiben, von der aus das Ende noch offen ist:

> Zuerst gehe ich – **nicht habituell immer, sondern nur dieses besondere Mal** – langsam. (Ich habe zwar vor, später schneller zu gehen, aber ob ich das tue, bleibt abzuwarten.)
>
> Zuerst **ist** er noch sehr schüchtern. *(Wir erwarten nun, dass er später weniger schüchtern sein wird. Es könnte aber auch anders kommen:)* Später dann versucht er sich zu öffnen, aber es gelingt ihm nicht.